# Connecting to remote mysql server using MacOS Terminal command line

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I have looked all over internet but cannot find right answer. I am learning php/mysql and have database on a remote mysql server at gearhost.com which I would like to connect to in order to train. I would like to use command line instead of phpMyAdmin to work on database.

My question is: how do I connect to database using Terminal? Is there a command that work with it or do I need to install something into MacOS first?

Answer (score 7):

You need to install MySQL client to access to remote MySQL server in your terminal. It is easy to install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

1. To install Homebrew run this command in your terminal (for more information about Homebrew and the installation navigate to its website):

   ```
   $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. To install MySQL client run this command in your terminal:

   ```
   $ brew install mysql
   ```
3. [Login](https://my.gearhost.com/account/login) in your GearHost account in your browser.
4. Open [Databases](https://my.gearhost.com/Databases) section in your account.
5. Find the host (something like: `mysqlx.gear.host`), username and password of your database.
6. Run this command in your terminal to access to your database. Replace `USER` with your username and `mysqlx.gear.host` with your host. After pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, the command asks for your password.

   ```
   $ mysql -u USER -h mysqlx.gear.host -p
   ```

   The output should be something like this:

   ```
   $ mysql -u USER -h mysqlx.gear.host -p
   Enter password:
   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MySQL connection id is 3304987
   Server version: 5.7.17-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

   Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

   Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
   owners.

   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

   mysql>
   ```

Comment: I stopped at step 3 as I don't understand that. What is gearHost. Why would anyone need an account on that website. Please explain

Comment: @RafaelSantos I explained those extra steps because the question is about connecting to `gearhost` db. Generally, others can skip 3-5, or consider that host as an example.

Comment: that was my bad, I didn't see in the question that it was specific to gearhost. Now it makes sense. Thanks